# Где лежит вёрстка NavBar в Yii2?

Tags: php, html, yii2

У меня на сайте на Yii2 вверху есть меню которое реализуется компонентом NavBar.

```
NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => Yii::$app->name,
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top logotype',
        ],
]);
```

Здест ключ 'class' определяет классы для тега nav.
Вот вёрстка.

```
  <nav id="w0" class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top logotype navbar">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#w0-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.php"></a>
     </div>
 <div id="w0-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul id="w1" class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav"><li><a href="/index.php?r=site%2Fregister">Регистрация</a></li>
    <li><a href="/index.php?r=site%2Flogin">Вход</a></li>
    </ul></div></div>
    </nav>
```

Внутри  есть блоки div , я хочу поменять это, добавить еще.
Где в yii2 находятся эти файлы? Поиск находит только только .css классы.
Я так понимаю что это где-то в логике компонента NavBar.
Как его править?

Comment: его не надо править так как они лежат в папке vendor, при обновлении композера у вас все слетит, необходимо переопределить класс NavBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавлять любое содержимое между открывающим и закрывающим методом виджета

```
<?=NavBar::begin();?>
<div>Любой контент</div>
<?=NavBar::end();?>
```

Answer (score -1):

За место навбара используйте простую верстку Вот пример того, как вы можете изменить код для применения своей верстки меню:

```
<div class="my-custom-navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?= Yii::$app->homeUrl ?>">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/about']) ?>">О нас</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/contact']) ?>">Заявка</a></li>
        <?php if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest): ?>
            <li><a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/register']) ?>">Регистрация</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/login']) ?>">Войти</a></li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li>
                <?= Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'], 'post')
                    . Html::submitButton('Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')', ['class' => ''])
                    . Html::endForm()
                ?>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```